# Why does my input signal timing change when changing interrupt method?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, avr, atmega

The AVR in use is ATmega2560.

I've got an input signal that has a pulse width of 1 second that is generated.

This signal is attached to an external interrupt pin on my AVR (INT0).

INT0 is being initialized as follows:

Code:

```
DDRD &= ~(1 << PD0);
PORTD |= (1 << PD0);
EIMSK  = 1 << INT0; // enable
EICRA |= (1 << ISC00) | (1 << ISC01); // trigger on rising edge

sei(); //global interrupts
```

The mission of the ISR for this external interrupt is to a) figure out which edge (first case should be rising) and b) perform action based on which edge

The ISR looks something like this:

Code:

```
ISR(INT0_vect)
{

if(EICRA == 0x02)
{
    // falling edge detected
    doFallingEdgeFunction_lightLED0();

    // quickly change the trigger to capture opposite edge
    EICRA |= (1 << ISC00) | (1 << ISC01); // trigger on rising edge

}

else if(EICRA == 0x03)
{
    doRisingEdgeFunction_lightLED1();

    // change trigger on falling edge
    EICRA = (1 << ISC01);
    EICRA &= ~(1 << ISC00);
}

}
```

It is able to detect the edges; the correct LEDs light up, but for some reason changing the edge interrupt bit in the ISR decreases my input signal to 0.1 second width instead of the full 1 second width.

On the scope, I see the original signal being mirrored but with 10x less width! If I remove the "switching trigger" items, the signal is fine.

Comment: In the else if, there's no need to clear out the ISC00 bit, as you do an assignment (thus clearing the rest of the contents) on the line above.  All that's doing is reassigning the EICRA a second time.

Answer (score 0):

From section 15.2.2, p. 114

> Note:
>    1. n = 3, 2, 1or 0. When changing the ISCn1/ISCn0 bits, the interrupt must be disabled by clearing its Interrupt Enable bit in the EIMSK
>   Register. Otherwise an interrupt can occur when the bits are changed.

EDIT:

> EIFR – External Interrupt Flag Register
>
> • Bits 7:0 – INTF7:0: External Interrupt Flags 7 - 0
>
> When an edge or logic change on the INT7:0 pin triggers an interrupt
>   request, INTF7:0 becomes set (one). If the I-bit in SREG and the
>   corresponding interrupt enable bit, INT7:0 in EIMSK, are set (one),
>   the MCU will jump to the interrupt vector. The flag is cleared when
>   the interrupt routine is executed. Alternatively, the flag can be
>   cleared by writing a logical one to it.

Try clearing the flag in the interrupt

```
EIFR = (1 << INT0);
```

Don't use

```
EIFR |= (1<< INT0);  // DO NOT USE
```

That will clear all pending flags.

Comment: I added EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT0); before changing the bits, and then EIMSK = (1 << INT0); after to re-enable. Didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @user791953 You can try clearing the flag by writing a 1 to it as well.

Comment: Hmm, I've added EIFR = (1 << INT0); in the ISR and same results.